# Сессия между пользователями FLASH

Tags: flash

Как сделать так что бы пользователи могли обмениваться данными только между собой как например реализовано в играz vkontakte. Например как где общаются только 2 человека или как в вормиксе играют 2 человека.

Answer (score 1):

есть такая технология cirrus:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/

у нее есть недостаток, соединение между клиентами может быть заблокировано настройками безопасности на уровне системы или местной сети 
поэтому для полноценного обмена в игре, только собственный промежуточный сервер является адекватным решением

Answer (score 0):

Они общаются не напрямую,а через сервер,по игровым идентификаторам,например.